# Want to Make Successive Backups for a database

Tags: c#, database-backups

I have written certain code to take the Backup of a Database, the application will take the Database Backup automatically at the time Specified. Now, I want some help to take Successive Backup of the Same Database which was taken previously and dont want to take Complete Database Backup again and again. Can any one Help me.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the backup features of the database engine itself?

Comment: No, i want to do it through Programatically, so that i can take the Backup at what ever time i want by putting the application in running state.

Comment: So you want an inremental backup? That is, a backup which you can apply to a previously taken full backup which will update the database to the point where the incremental backup was taken, but which by itself only contains the changes which have occurred since the previous full backup?

Comment: @Xavinou, I am Using SqlServer 2005 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to make incremental backups with MS Sql Server in c# : http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1849

Comment: Thanks for Reply. After making trails based on the tips in the website I will reply the status. @Xavinou